# Lookup links not opening associated record from List form in Sharepoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, lookup-column, hyperlink

I have set up a list that has a lookup field on Documents. This works nicely except for one thing.

If I open a record (by double clicking on the record), a panel pops out showing a form populated with the data for that record.

The document(s) that I have selected in that lookup field for that record are displayed as hyperlinks (coloured) and when I hover over the link, the cursor turns to a hand indicating that I ought to be able to click on the link in order to open the document.

But when I do this,  the field changes to edit mode and the document does not open.   This going to be a major problem for our users who want to navigate from the record to the associated document.

Do others see this problem?     Is this intended behaviour?   Is there a workaround/fix?

The links are clickable and do work as I had hoped in the actual List view and on the form if I switch to Classic view.

Thanks

Richard

Comment: Sorry forgot to say that this is in Office 365 - so I am guessing that this is with Sharepoint 2016.    PS:  I am Sharepoint beginner

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, I can reproduce the condition as you that I can just edit the lookup column instead of link to the document property.

[image]

It’s by default that we can only edit the column value in the details pane. As a workaround, I recommend the user open the document link directly in the view instead of details pane.

[image]